# Pointer math in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to use some pinvoke code to call a C function.  The function fills a buffer with data.

The structure is set up as a DWORD for the length, followed by a string.  How do I extract the string from the IntPtr?

```
 IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nRequiredSize);
 PInvokedFunction(buffer, nRequiredSize);
 string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(buffer + 4); //this is an error.
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
IntPtr sBuffer = new IntPtr( buffer.ToInt64() + 4 );
string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto( sBuffer );
```

So your code is 64bit safe.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was the following, though the use of the UnmanagedMemoryStream seems a bit of a hack.

```
 IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)nRequiredSize);
 PInvokedFunction(buffer, nRequiredSize);
 UnmanagedMemoryStream memStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(buffer.ToPointer(), nRequiredSize);
 memStream.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(memStream.PositionPointer);
 string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work, although I think I like [Matt Ellis's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215624/pointer-math-in-c#215660) better.

I changed the IntPtr on the [DllImport] to a byte[].

```
 //allocate the buffer in .Net
 byte[] buffer = new byte[nRequiredSize];

 //call the WIN32 function, passing it the allocated buffer
 PInvokedFunction(buffer);

 //get the string from the 5th byte
 string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(buffer, 4));
```